# How to test logging in junit5?

Tags: java, testing, logging, junit-rule, junit5

I am transitioning from junit4 to junit5 on a project and trying to figure out how to test logs.  Previously, I used

```
@Rule
OutputCapture outputCapture = new OutputCapture();
```

and would then write an assertion using `outputCapture.toString()`, for example

`assertThat(outputCapture.toString(),containsString("status=200"));`

Since `@Rule` annotation hasn't been implemented yet in junit5, I can't use outputCapture.  Any ideas what to do instead?  Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

There's an extension provided for the same and you can use it as below:

```
@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
public class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    void myTestCase(CapturedOutput capturedOutput) {
        assertTrue(capturedOutput.getOut().contains("expected string"));
        assertTrue(capturedOutput.getErr().contains("expected string"));
    }
}
```

Comment: import org.springframework.boot.test.system.CapturedOutput;
import org.springframework.boot.test.system.OutputCaptureExtension;

Comment: @AnthonyW What about not spring(boot) projects?

Answer (score 7):

We stumbled upon the same issue during our JUnit5 migration. After some research, I found a technical solution but it didn't seem like someone made a testing library out of it just yet. So that's what I did. It's published to Maven Central so you can use it right away:

https://github.com/netmikey/logunit

You can use it as follows:

```
public class MyModuleTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    LogCapturer logs = LogCapturer.create().captureForType(MyModule.class);

    @Test
    public void testLogging() {
        // ... do the testing ...

        // Run assertions on the logged messages
        logs.assertContains("Some message");
    }
}
```

(see the project's [README](https://github.com/netmikey/logunit/blob/master/README.md) for more examples)

Comment: implemented your library, excellent addition to my project!. Nice work!

Answer (score 3):

The [Migration Tip](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips) from the [JUnit5 documentation](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips) clearly states that -

> `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` no longer exist; superseded by `@ExtendWith`; see the following section for partial rule support.

For the purpose of using the [existing `@Rule` support from JUnit 4](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-rulesupport), there is though a way suggested for method or class level annotations.

> As in JUnit 4, Rule-annotated fields as well as methods are supported.
>   By using these class-level extensions on a test class such Rule
>   implementations in legacy codebases can be left unchanged including
>   the JUnit 4 rule import statements.
>
> This limited form of Rule support can be switched on by the
>   class-level annotation
>   `org.junit.jupiter.migrationsupport.rules.EnableRuleMigrationSupport`

---

A better option would still be redesigning your test suite to use the [Extension Model from JUnit5](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) if you're using it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also easily test the log output written to *System.out* by quickly implementing a solution on your own as follows:

```
// Configure System.out to be written to a buffer from which we can read
PrintStream realSysOut = System.out;
BufferedOutputStream sysOutBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(sysOutBuffer));
...
// Perform some action which logs something to System.out
System.out.println("Some random content written to System.out");
...
// Assert that a given string was written in the meantime to System.out
assertThat(new String(buffer.toByteArray()), containsString("random content"));
...
// Don't forget to bring back the real System.out at the end of the test
System.setOut(realSysOut);
```

In the case of checking log output written to System.err, you can equivalently implement it by replacing *System.setOut(...)* with *System.setErr(...)* and *System.out* with *System.err* in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is to check if the class under test writes correct logs, another way is to configure a `ListAppender` (which is already provided by LogBack) and point your logger name to that appender in your logging configuration. The appender writes the logs to a `java.util.List` and then you can get the appender via the logging framework's API. Then you can check the contents of the list.

LogBack's default ListAppender is not thread-safe so you may want to write something similar with any synchronization if necessary.

Here is how we do it with SLF4j and logback:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
import ch.qos.logback.core.read.ListAppender
....    
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("some.logger")
ListAppender appender = (ListAppender) logger.getAppender("SOME_LIST")
```

In your logback.xml file, you configure the appender:

```
<appender name="SOME_LIST" class="ch.qos.logback.core.read.ListAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

<logger name="some.logger" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SOME_LIST" />
  </logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Springboot, you can use CapturedOutput and check if what you logged appeared.

Your class:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyClass {
    public void myLogFunction() {
        log.info("Hello world !";
    }
}
```

Your test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.system.CapturedOutput;
import org.springframework.boot.test.system.OutputCaptureExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@ExtendWith(OutputCaptureExtension.class)
class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    void MyLogTest (CapturedOutput output) {
    // my conditions
    when(...).thenReturn(...);
    
    // my tests having some logs
    myLogFunction();
    
    // checking my logs appeared in log output
    Assertions.assertTrue(output.getOut().contains("Hello world !"));
    }
}
```